# win32 API for running other exe

Tags: winapi, api

I wanted to know the win32 API to run the regsvr32 programatically.

I have one application through which I can communicate with COM port devices. but to achieve communication, I have to register MSCOMM32.ocx using regsvr32.exe, But now I wanted to add this provision in my code. so that no need to run regsvr manually.

Comment: It is called an install program.  Which you also need to deploy mscomm32.ocx, it is not included with Windows.  You cannot copy it along with your program, you'll break other programs since it is a COM server.

Answer (score 2):

The windows CreateProcess API call is what you're looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This is not the correct solution to swapnil's problem. It may well answer the direct question, but swapnil's proposed solution is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a combination of win32 api calls:

- LoadLibrary() to load the Dll
- GetProcAddress() to get the address of the DllRegisterServer() function
- If GetProcAddress finds that function, call it to register the Dll.

The DllRegisterServer function is explained here: [MSDN: DllRegisterServer Entry Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682162%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Good answer, but as they're using mscomm32.ocx, I expect they're also using VB6 which doesn't (natively) support calling functions by address.

Answer (score 1):

You've already had the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965786/win32-api-for-running-other-exe/6965857#6965857) to the title of the question.

As for registering the DLL, I presume you're using VB6 with which you can not (easily) [register it directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965786/win32-api-for-running-other-exe/6971746#6971746).

The correct way to register it is to do it as part of the installer.
Doing it in the app is too late as you (most likely) won't normally have the admin permissions required to register it.

To ask the user to run it as an admin, you can use [ShellExecute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) and pass "runas" as the verb with "regsvr32.exe" and the path to mscomm32.ocx as the file and parameters.
For VB6:

```
  ShellExecute 0, "runas", "regsvr32.exe", """c:\blah.dll""", "c:\", 0
```