# How to check Registered dll in windows?

Tags: windows, dll

I wanted to register mscomm32.ocx using regsvr.exe, I have done that.
Now I wanted to check whether that .ocx is registered or not, depending on that I can take action.

Comment: possible duplicate of [win32 API for running other exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965786/win32-api-for-running-other-exe)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966625/win32-api-for-running-other-exe  How many user accounts did you create?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to know that? If it's already registered, you can call `regsvr.exe mscomm32.ocx` again and it won't do anything. If you want to uninstall it, call `regsvr.exe -u mscomm32.ocx`. And if it's already uninstalled, it also won't do anything.

Basically, you don't need to worry whether it's installed or not - if you need it, install it, if you don't need it, uninstall it, and the Windows API will take care of the rest.